# WooCommerce custom product type option hiding logic not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

This question is an addition to my already existing question:

[WooCommerce custom product type option not hiding custom product tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67341234/woocommerce-custom-product-type-option-not-hiding-custom-product-tab/67343450?noredirect=1)

With the help of `7uc1f3r` I've managed to show/hide my custom tab and checkbox in case my checkbox gets checked/unchecked and the product types are correct.

Also, I've changed my specs a bit. So the checkbox should now be visible when:

- It's not an external product
- It's not downloadable
- It's not virtual
- It's not a service (comes from WooCommerce Germanzied = Dienstleistung)

[image]

I've tried now multiple approaches to accomplish this without any/just partly success:

**1) Use hiding classes from WooCommerce for my checkbox and tab:**

For this approach I've changed my wrapper classes of the checkbox:

```
'wrapper_class' => 'hide_if_external hide_if_downloadable hide_if_virtual hide_if_service'
```

Also, the tab classes getting changed:

```
'class' => [ 'hide_if_external', 'hide_if_downloadable', 'hide_if_virtual', 'hide_if_service', 'show_if_batches' ]
```

Two problems appeared now:

1. When I save the product with downloadable and batches checked, reload the page, uncheck downloadable, uncheck batches, check downloadable and uncheck it without checking batches, the batches tab appears again.
2. `hide_if_service` is not working since it doesn't implement any hiding logic, and I'm unable to add this because everything else is buggy.

I'm really lost now since it's not working. This is my JS stuff for this approach:

```
$( '#woocommerce-product-data .type_box input, #woocommerce-product-data select#product-type' ).change( function () {
    showHideBatches();
} ).trigger( 'change' );

function showHideBatches() {
    let showIfBatches = $( '.show_if_batches' );
    if ($( '#woocommerce-product-data input#_batches' ).is( ':checked' )) {
        showIfBatches.show();
    } else {
        showIfBatches.hide();
        $( '.general_options.general_tab > a' ).trigger( 'click' );
    }
}
```

**2) Use hiding classes from WooCommerce for my checkbox only (most liked):**

I've come up with this idea since the other one totally failed. The idea behind this is to only give the checkbox the hiding classes:

```
'wrapper_class' => 'hide_if_external hide_if_downloadable hide_if_virtual hide_if_service'
```

The tab will only have the batches show class:

```
'class' => [ 'show_if_batches' ]
```

Now I've switches to JS and developed this little function to enable/disable my `batches` checkbox in case it's hidden:

```
$( '#woocommerce-product-data .type_box input, #woocommerce-product-data select#product-type' ).change( function () {
    showHideBatches();
    uncheckBatches();
} ).trigger( 'change' );

function uncheckBatches() {
    if (!$( '#woocommerce-product-data label[for=_batches]' ).is( ':visible' )) {
        $( '#woocommerce-product-data input#_batches' ).prop( 'checked', false );
    }
}
```

But when triggering now the downloadable checkbox, the logic seems to work but not how it should. I need to enable/disable this checkbox multiple times to get this working. Also, the services checkbox is not covered here.

I've tried multiple things to detect if my checkbox appears or not like `MutationObserver` or custom event types - none of them are working.

Any idea how to make this working?